# How to set the value of TextView in Custom Dialog in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to set the value of TextView in custom dialog box after I clicked in one of the fragments in Activity. Dialog was running fine with custom text view after it is being called. The problem is that it always shows **NullPointerException** when I tried to call **changeMessageText("Hello")** function.

**ProgressDialogFragment.java**

```
public class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        private TextView txtMessage;
        private AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder;

        public static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance(AlertDialog.Builder builder){
            ProgressDialogFragment progressDialogFragment = new ProgressDialogFragment();
            progressDialogFragment.mBuilder = builder;
            return progressDialogFragment;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress, null);
            txtMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);

            changeMessageText("Hello World by default"); // this one works

            mBuilder.setView(view);

            return mBuilder.create();

        }
        public void changeMessageText(String text){
            txtMessage.setText(text);
        }
}
```

**Sample Code** after the button Clicked

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ProgressDialogFragment progressDialogFragment = ProgressDialogFragment.newInstance(builder);
progressDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"progress_dialog");
// dialog box shows until the following function is called.

progressDialogFragment.changeMessageText("Hello");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `progressDialogFragment.changeMessageText("Hello");` called, `txtMessage` is not created yet.

1) Add `private String message;` to `ProgressDialogFragment`.

2) Change `changeMessageText`

```
public void changeMessageText(String text){
    message = text;
    if(txtMessage != null){
        txtMessage.setText(text);
   }            
}
```

3) add after `mBuilder.setView(view);`

```
if(message!=null && !message.isEmpty()){
    txtMessage.setText(message);
}
```

4) Remove `changeMessageText("Hello World by default");` in `onCreateDialog`

And. It Doesn't Work for Me.

`View view = getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress, null);`

I change it.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_progress, null);
```

Hope it will help you.